# Form inside another form rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

Let me first say that I'm a beginner with web development, so stay with me! 
The thing is that I have a page where rails will gather all the rooms from the database. And then list them in a table. So far so good. But I want the user to be able to click a button next to each row, that will book the room for the user.

Atm I have it working 80%. The thing is that I have a form inside another form, so when the user press book then it books the last row in the table ofc! So how do I fix this? I read about using javascript to fix this, but as a beginner I dont really know javascript.

I could put the Reservation.new form inside the all_rooms form and it will work. But I need to get the value from the datetimepicker from the user also. Thats why I put it outside.

```
<%= form_for(Reservation.new, remote: true, format: :js, url: {controller: "booker", action: "create"}) do |new_res| %>
  <div class="calender">
    <%= new_res.date_field :date, :value => (Time.now + 6.days).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') ,  min: 6.days.from_now, max: 90.days.from_now %>
  </div>
  <div class="time">
    <%= new_res.time_select :start_time , {:default => {:hour => 10 , :minute => 00}, minute_step: 15 , :start_hour => 8, :end_hour => 18, :hour => 11} %>
    <%= new_res.time_select :end_time , {:default => {:hour => 14 , :minute => 00}, minute_step: 15 , :start_hour => 8, :end_hour => 18, :hour => 11} %>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="t_Data">
  <table class ="rooms_to_book">
    <tr>
      <th>Namn</th>
      <th>Storlek</th>
      <th>Byggnad</th>
      <th>Utrustning</th>
      <th>Booka</th>
    </tr>
    <% @all_rooms.each do |r| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= r.room %></td>
        <td><%= r.room_size %></td>
        <td><%= r.building %></td>
        <td><%= r.room_description %></td>
        <td>
          <%= new_res.hidden_field :room, value: r.room %>
          <%= new_res.hidden_field :building, value: r.building %>
          <%= new_res.hidden_field :room_size, value: r.room_size %>
          <%= new_res.hidden_field :room_description, value: r.room_description %>
          <%= new_res.submit  "Book" %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
<% end %>
```

So question is. How do I fix this problem, so when I press book. I create a new reservation and gather all the data + the date the user picked. So its unique for each row.

Comment: use `fields_for` method to make `@all_rooms` available in the form

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all the hidden fields you could name each of the submit buttons like this

> `<%= new_res.submit  "Book", name: r.id %>`

then inside your create action in your controller extract the room id from the params hash, as it will be a key in the params hash pointing to "Book". Then using the id you can find the associated Room object and create a new Reservation using everything you had in the hidden fields.